# Why my filter buttons are returning to line?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hi I m using bootstrap 4

I m trying to master the grid features of bootstrap4, in my exercice I try to show a row of a search field and some buttons (filters + add button) as shown in the image 1, my goal is to make it all inline with a little space between search field , filters and add button .

Here is what I m trying right know :

```
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-xl-9">
            <div class="col-xl-7">
                <input type="search" class="form-control col-xl-11  " autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="{{'autoEcoleV01App.constants.search' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-5 ">
                <button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4  " jhiSortBy="nom">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nom">Nom</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4" jhiSortBy="prenom">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.prenom">Prenom</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4  " jhiSortBy="nid">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nid">Nid</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3">
            <button id="jh-create-entity"
                class="btn btn-primary  float-right jh-create-entity create-candidat col-xl-11   "
                [routerLink]="['/candidat/new']">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
                <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.home.createLabel">
                    Create new Candidat
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is resulting of the following :

[image: space issue]

I can't understand why my filters are not in the empty space even if I taked care that every child sum doesn't excede 12 column size !!

[Here is a fiddle reproduction of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/72yevmat/1/)

Comment: create jsfiddle snippet please

Comment: updated with fiddle link @JanakPrajapati

Comment: It seems you are just using columns for the sake of using them; Bootstrap provided a structure that you should follow in order for the columns and other styles to apply correctly; for example, columns should be immediate children of a `row`, you are just nesting columns without building a new row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has unnecessary divs and bit complex in code

My solution has been created from bootstrap grids
Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content. It’s built with flexbox.

In my solution you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. You can also your predefined classes of bootstrap.

Hope it helps

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
<input type="search" class="form-control col-xl-11  " autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="{{'autoEcoleV01App.constants.search' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" />
</div>
<div class="col">
<button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4  " jhiSortBy="nom">
            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nom">Nom</span>
            <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4" jhiSortBy="prenom">
            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.prenom">Prenom</span>
            <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="btn  float-left btn-outline-secondary col-xl-4  " jhiSortBy="nid">
            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nid">Nid</span>
            <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
        </button>
</div>
<div class="col">
<button id="jh-create-entity"
        class="btn btn-primary  float-right jh-create-entity create-candidat col-xl-11   "
        [routerLink]="['/candidat/new']">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
        <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.home.createLabel">
            Create new Candidat
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

You can improve grid layout 
Have check more examples for same : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: You should provide an explanation *why* your solution works and what does it do; not just put the code without context

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @IvanS95. I have added bit of explanation